# Normal memory usage in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm wondering how much memory usage is normal for a ruby process in a rails application? I really need something to benchmark against.

In my dev environment WEBrick a single ruby process uses about 61mb to handle 10 simultaneous requests going non stop. In my prod environment Apache2+Passenger starts 7 ruby processes  to handle the same ammount of requests. Each of those processes also use up about 60mb. Is this normal?

Also, where do I configure how many ruby processes Passenger can start? Or will it start as many as there is memory available for?

Thank you!

ps. Using Rails3 beta. ds.

Answer (score 0):

The memory usage depend of your application. How route/controller/model have you.

60Mo of memory seems not important. It's a normal thing.

Answer (score 0):

Right now our 5 ruby processes consume a total of 423 MB compared to the MySQL Server with 62.5 MB. The app runs on about 5000 lines of code without any significantly large computations.